# ImportError with Relative Imports When Debugging a Multi-directory Python Project in VSCode

Tags: python, debugging, importerror, visual-studio-debugging, relative-import

I'm working on a Python project with multiple directories and facing an issue when trying to debug using VSCode. The project structure is as follows:

```
├── main_script.py
├── plots
│   ├── plot_script_1.py
│   └── plot_script_2.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── analysis
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── analysis_module.py
│   ├── frameworks
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── framework_module.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── utility_module.py
└── tests
    └── test_framework.py
```

In `framework_module.py`, I'm trying to import from other modules:

```
from ..analysis.analysis_module import dummy_analysis
from ..utils.utility_module import dummy_util

def framework_analysis(arguments):
    # Rest of the code...
```

Running `main_script.py` from the terminal works fine, but when I try to debug `framework_module.py` using breakpoints in VSCode, I encounter the following `ImportError`:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
  File "{file}", line {line}, in <module>
    from ..analysis.analysis_module import dummy_analysis
```

This occurs even when I include a if `__name__` == `'__main__'`: block in framework_module.py for testing purposes.

What I've tried:

- Setting up a `__main__` block in framework_module.py and running it as a script.
- Checking for incorrect paths or misspellings in the import statements.

I'm unsure how to resolve these import errors when debugging individual modules in a multi-directory project. How should I properly set up debugging in this scenario with VSCode?

I already checked upon the other issues related to relative imports here, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: How are you running it on terminal?

Comment: I was using the vscode "run and debug" option

Comment: Can you find the command line and the working dir specified in the run configuration? Does it have a "run as a module" option?

Comment: Yes, I can find these directories. Regarding as running as a module: I've never thought about that, I will try to look for it

Comment: Running as a module is the standard/recommended way of running a python script - this way imports are resolved correcty

Answer (score 0):

You may want to configure the launch options of vscode for Python scripts. Here is an example: create a file `.vscode/launch.json` under your working directory and its content should be like:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "cwd": "/path/to/your/working/directory",
            "args": [
                "--some", "launch", "arguments"
            ],
            "env": {
                "ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES": "SOME_VALUE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This makes the debugging launch in vscode equivalent to run this command under `/path/to/your/working/directory`:

```bash
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES=SOME_VALUE python ${file} --some launch arguments
```

If something is still unclear, please refer to [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) for further information.

Comment: Thank you. There's something that the documentation didn't made clear to me. Let's say I want to debug `framework_module.py`. On VSCode should I open the project top level directory or the `frameworks` directory? Also, on `"cwd": "/path/to/your/working/directory",` the path should refer to the top level or the directory the script being run is?

Comment: Open the project directory (that is, where `main_script.py` is located), and the `cwd`  should also be the same directory. In this case, vscode should work fine when you run `main_script.py`.

Comment: Thank you for the continuous help. I set up the json file with the command line arguments but they are not being passed to the vscode terminal. I added a statement to print the args to the code and it returns: 
`Command line arguments: ['/Users/danilocoutodesouza/Documents/Programs_and_scripts/lorenz-cycle/lorenz_cycle.py']` 

but on json it is: 

`"args": [
                "samples/Reg1-Representative_NCEP-R2.nc", "-f", "-r"
            ]`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is according to your description. It seems like the `launch.json` doesn't work in your workspace. Where do you place `launch.json`? If you're not sure about where to place the file, maybe you can create this file with vscode instead of manually. Click 'create a launch.json file' in the 'Run' toolbar panel and this would get your configuration file placed at the right place.

Comment: It is on the root directory, under .vscode. I created it with vscode and then edited

Comment: Is there a way to configure this `launch.json` to run the script using the `-m` switch?